# Plugin directory of Firefox 5.0

Tags: firefox, debian, flash

I just downloaded the new Firefox in Debian and working it. BUt the flash is not working, though it works well in Chrome. I installed the shared library and the adobe says copy that to the firefox plugins directory. I use firefox from the extracted tar file which I downloaded

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://ask.debian.net (which is not a SE website) might be a better choice for Debian questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Flash has gotten currupted probaly a config file.
Check this out see if it helps your issue:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove flashplugin-installer

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sevenmachines/flash

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install flashplugin64-installer`

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+question/157822

Of course assmuming that your running 64bit Ubuntu. If not then install `flashplugin-installer` instead.